# How to bind Laravel Ajax response data into route link

Tags: php, ajax, concatenation, response, laravel-7

I need to bind the response data `id` to my `<a href='{{route('')}}'> </a>`

I get the data from a Ajax request and i need to edit function for a specific loaded data by its id

this is how i get the data to my view

```
   function fetchRecords(id){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'detailed-registrations/getCompetitionAjax/'+id,
                        type: 'get',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(response){
                            var len = 0;
                            $('#userTable').empty(); // Empty <tbody>
                            if(response['data'] != null){
                                len = response['data'].length;
                            }
                            if(response['data']  != null){
                                var tr_str =
                                "<div class='primary-bg-color p-3 mb-3'>" +
                                    "<div class='row pb-4'>" +
                                        "<div class='col'>" +
                                            "<div class='prime-color1'>  Competition Details" +
                                                "<div class='font-size-14 p'>" +
                                                    "<span style='text-transform: capitalize;'>" + response['data'].type + "</span>" +' | '+ response['location'].sport.name +
                                                "</div>" +
                                                "<div class='font-sec5 text-center text-md-left mb-2 pt-1'>"+
                                                    "<img src='{{asset('/images/sketches/1x/ic_map_pin_active.png')}}' alt='Location'>"+
                                                    " " + response['location'].location + ""+
                                                "</div>"+
                                                // "<li>" + response['data'].name + "</li>" +
                                                // "<li>" + response['data'].type + "</li>" +
                                                "<li>" + response['data'].id + "</li>" +

                                            "</div>"+
                                        "</div>"+
                                        "<div><a href='{{ route('competitions.edit', $id) }}' class='button pnt button-outline mr-sm-3 mb-2 float-right'>Edit Details</a></div>"+
                                    "</div>"
                                "</div>";
                                $("#userTable").append(tr_str);
                            }
```

Instead of using $id i need to use the id when i get through the response, something like below code but it does not work.

```
"<div><a href='{{ route('competitions.edit',"+ response['data'].id +") }}'
```

I'm able to print the id in a div tag as shown in the image below

[image]

Comment: you want to pass to the `fetchRecords` the ID which you have display

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the value from Javascript to PHP, or in this case the Laravel blade {{ }} directive. Since it will not execute. It will only execute on page load.

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. instead of using `{{ route() }}`, just directly use the url path `/competitions/id/edit`. For example in your case:

```
"<div><a href='/competitions/"+response['data'].id+"/edit' "
```

2. Or, you can just generate the route link in backend, such as your Controller, and send the route link to frontend.

```php
// generate the link
$route = route('competitions.edit', $id);
return $route; // include into your other data
```

and use it directly in your javascript response

```js
"<div><a href='"+response['data'].route+"' "
```